# deformable objects on gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, i'm working with gazebo annd ROS, i want to know if it's possible the deformation of objects.
Any idea? Thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/535/deformable-objects-on-gazebo/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/124/monidiaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/305/spawning-animated-deformable-objects-in-gazebo/#314

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2